# Adding sails application name as prefix in all links

Tags: sails.js

I need to add a variable in sails configuration that refer to the application name and use this name as a prefix in all generated links as css, js,images files
sailsjs generate these link automatically and add include commands to the page.
So, how can i modify this generation of links to include the name as prefix

Comment: did you try anything or you want SO users to write code for you?

Comment: Yes i´m trying a lot, and i´m not waiting for other user user to write me the code.
There is something missing.
You told me a solution with nginx. and i didn´t get the result i want
So i asked again in another concept explaining the problem that i have.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [HTML base tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element). If your application name is "sails-app-1" then:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="https://example.com/sails-app-1/">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="example-image.gif" width="100" height="100" alt="https://example.com/sails-app-1/example-image.gif">
        <a href="page-1.html" title="Relative paths will be appended to the base tag's href attribute.">https://example.com/sails-app-1/page-1.html</a>
        <a href="/page-2.html" title="Absolute paths will not be appended to the base tag's href attribute.">https://example.com/page-2.html</a>
        <a href="https://example.com/page-3.html" title="Absolute URLs will not be affected.">https://example.com/page-3.html</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Relative paths for script, link, image, and anchor tags will be appended to the base tag's href attribute.

Absolute paths and URLs will not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think your most optimal solution is rewriting links or modifying project structures, you are already inside a project!

Here is what I suggest you do: Use Apache as a reverse proxy to your sails instances by adding this to you site configuration:

```
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /sails-project-1/ http://127.0.0.1:1337/
ProxyPassReverse /sails-project-1/ http://127.0.0.1:1337/
ProxyPass /sails-project-2/ http://127.0.0.1:1338/
ProxyPassReverse /sails-project-1/ http://127.0.0.1:1338/
ProxyPass /sails-project-3/ http://127.0.0.1:1339/
ProxyPassReverse /sails-project-1/ http://127.0.0.1:1339/
```

also you may need to add `process.env.npm_project_name` to `prefix` in `config/blueprints.js`

Note: `process.env.npm_project_name` is only available if you run your app using `npm start` rather than `sails lift`